# Are these bikes real from Aliexpress?

Tags: mountain-bike

I wanted to buy a bike and started checking for one online. I went through some nice ones on Aliexpress.com but the price is very suspicious to me. It's not just the price but also the free shipping via those expensive shipping companies.

Can someone (especially someone who understands Chinese) tell me if those are real bikes?

Check [THIS](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mountain-bike-folding-bicycle-mountain-bike-variable-speed/1770766581.html) link as an example.

Comment: Those are what are referred to as ["bicycle shaped objects"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/887/163) (or BSOs).

Comment: Buy from your Local Bike Shop  (LBS). If you buy online, the LBS loses business and will not make a profit. Do you think they will go that extra mile to help when your BSO starts falling apart (as it will)? If you buy from an LBS, they make a profit, stay in business, and can offer you support and bundle deals on the bike and clothes, helmet and maybe shoes that you'll need.

Comment: Er ... rant mode off now ...

Comment: And even if it were real. A **folding** mountain bike? Really? Also, what kind of components do you expect if you spend less money on the whole bike than most people do for their bolt-on grips?

Comment: @andy256 I think its fair to say that some bike shops are good, others will try to rip you off. Just like any other type of business wherever you happen to be in the world.

Comment: @andy256 - The margin on the actual bike is very slim. Much like movie theaters, the profit is not in the ticket/bike, but in the extras like helmets, tubes, tires, water bottles, bottle cages, pedals, shoes, shorts, etc etc etc.

Comment: Aliexpress is, in general, a bit of a shady site.

Comment: It seems really shady to me. The seller has no detailed seller ratings! I would avoid, but if you have to buy pay with paypal so you do have protection if something does go wrong.